# Datatables only shows the first row when multiple rows returned from server

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I recently updated my datatables from 1.9.4 to 1.10.2.  Most of the functionality works but sometimes I get weird issues in which the Datatable only shows one row even when there are mulitple rows returned from the server.

I also get weird errors like

[image]

Does anyone know off the top of their head what could be causing these issues? What dramatic changes from 1.9.4 to 1.10.2 happened?  The website says that Datatables 1.10.2 is completely backwards compatible but it doesnt seem to be the case...

THanks

Comment: http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4 explains exactly what is happening. DataTables is looking for a key value (Id) in your aaData that is not present. Look at the data object returned from Ajax source  to see if Id is present and where you expect it.

Comment: it is there and it does show it.  I believe it is relating to the issue of datatables not showing all of the rows for some reason.  I wish I could post the code but it is a huge project

Comment: We just need an example row and the .datatables initializing config (i.e) the columns part and whether it is Ajax sourced.