# DataTables with Ajax return only one Row on DotNetCore

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

im trying to get some datas with AJAX from an action on my controller in DotNetCore. The result should show 6 rows in DataTable and it shows Only One, and i also have to wait like a minute or two for the datatable to LOAD the row. Also the table doesnt look responsive at all, it looks old fashioned , and font-awesome is not working properly, and i have no idea why all of these are happening (got bootsrap and fontawesome css imported).

Can someone please help me?

Also when i tried to get the data from the Model (without AJAX and DataTables) it showed me 6 rows.

Here's the code:

Index.cshtml

```
  <link href="~/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<h4>Products</h4>
<hr />
<div class="container">
        
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            
        </div>
        <table class="table tbl-products table-responsive table-bordered table-striped text-center">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>

                <td>Name</td>

                <td>Category</td>

                <td>Price</td>

                <td>Quantity</td>

                <td></td>
            </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.0.3/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var table = $('.tbl-products').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Products")',
                    dataSrc: "",
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log('success' + msg.success);
                    
                }
            },
                columns:[
                    {
                        data: "id"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "name"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "category"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "price"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "quantity"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "id",
                        render: function(data) {
                            var url = "@Url.Action("Edit","Products")" + "/" + data;
                            return "<a href='" + url + "' class='btn btn-primary'>View</a> <a class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "language": {
                    "legthMenu": '_MENU_ entries per page',
                    "search": '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>',
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
                        "next": '<i class"fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

ProductsController.cs:

```
public IActionResult GetProducts()
        {
            var model = _repository.Product.ToList();
 
            return Ok(model);
        }
```

This is the output in Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at dataTables.bootstrap.js:47
    at dataTables.bootstrap.js:39
    at dataTables.bootstrap.js:41
```

Here's the picture from the view:
**p.s dont mind that [object Object] in Category row**
[image]

Comment: What result you get from the database query? How many rows it is displaying when executed without datatables integration.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell, that when i tried to get the data from the Model(without AJAX and DataTables), it showed me 6 rows

Comment: `dataSrc: ""` is used to read a *plain array* in dataTables.... is your `model` a plain array?

Comment: Sorry but i cant understand you what you mean with _plain array_

Comment: [DataTables dataSrc documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) - where I'm interpreting a *plain array* to be `["foo", "bar", baz"]`. What format is your response object in?

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169189/datatables-only-shows-the-first-row-when-multiple-rows-returned-from-server) may also be relevant to your issue. It would be helpful for you to post an example of the return object so we can see if it's the data format, datatables, or your controller action that's causing the issue.

Comment: i think i would be a _plain array_ because every item in _model_ in _ProductsController_ would be an object with id,name,price and quantity, all as int's,string and decimal

Comment: @wahwahwah just edited , here's the output from console.log